# Date.now() in a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="case in cases">
{{(((Date.now()/1000) - case.date_case_modified)/(60*60*24))}}
</div>
```

I am accessing an api that tosses me a date in strtotime format and I'm trying to take that on the front end and calculate the time since that day in days.

Comment: JavaScript code should be in your controller, not in your template. Only scope methods and fields can be accessed from the template.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what strtotime format is? Could you give an example. If I search google it just gives me a PHP function. On another note you should use `http://momentjs.com/` to calculate differences in time, since it is way easier to work with (and makes the code readable).

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use an expression in between the curly braces in AngularJS, I believe it can handle only simple and basic stuff. What you probably want to do is call a method in your $scope from the expression.

For instance - you could do it like so:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item.name }} that was {{ timeDiffInMinutes(item.date) }} minutes ago.</li>
```

Where the controller would look like:

```
app.controller('mycontroller', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.items =  [ 
        { name: 'event 1', date: 1422561182654 },
        { name: 'event 2', date: 1422561184654 },
        { name: 'event 3', date: 1422561186654 }];

    $scope.timeDiffInMinutes = function(otherDate) {
        var now = Date.now();
        var difference = otherDate - now;        
        var differenceInMinutes = difference / 60;
        return differenceInMinutes; 
    };
}]);
```

Here you can see my full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yvuhgaxb/1/

And indeed - make as commented by Kristian - there are plenty of nice JavaScript libraries out there that format the difference for you nicely with stuff like 'a minute ago' and things like that.